# Hexagon "maze" algorithm

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Can anyone suggest a good algorithm to create structures like this?

[image: a hexagonal maze]

Note that what I what I am asking for is not a true maze with one start and one solution. Rather, it's for a video game, so like in Pac-Man there can be multiple entrances and exits.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm  If you want to have multiple paths you can destroy some walls afterward.

Comment: The usual method is: Start with no walls.  Select at random a location where a wall can be placed, and add this wall to your maze if and only if doing so would not separate the maze into two unconnected regions.  Repeat.

Comment: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2014/12/21/rooms-and-mazes/ has a really wonderful discussion of not only the basic algorithm, but also several elaborations that you may or may not care about.

Comment: How do I adapt these to the hexagon shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a good algorithm here:

http://www.dllu.net/programming/hexmaze/

And it's in a programming language I can understand.